# How to align the x-lable with bar based on barplot() in R?

Tags: r

I want to draw a histogram to appear frequency of factors of my data named temp_table ：

```
CCD |  CNT | cTAL|DCT  | G |IMCD|LDLIM|LDLOM |mTAL | OMCD | S1 | S2 | S3 | SDL | tAL
11  |  6   | 7   | 8   | 5 |  8 |  4  |  9   |  7  |  7   | 7  |  7 |  7 |  10  |  7
```

Therefore I try the barplot() firstly and the result:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCFcu.png)

I found I should rotate the x-lab 90 degrees if I want to show them all, so I tried following command:
`barplot(temp_table, xlab = "", xaxt = "n")
axis(side = 1,las=2,labels = rownames(temp_table),
     at = 1:nrow(temp_table), cex.axis = 0.7)`

The result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W80hf.png)

As you can see the x-labels cannot match with bars.
I think that I did something wrong when I set the values of parameter "at =".

Thus, how can I fix this problem?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `barplot` function returns the x-values of the bar midpoints, which you can use with the `at` argument. Try this:

```
labls = c("CCD", "CNT", "cTAL", "DCT", "G") 
vals = c(11, 6, 7, 8, 5)
b = barplot(vals)
axis(side=1, las=2, labels=labls, at=b)
```

Comment: Cool! I made it! Thank you so much!